# Should I use the function's constants when testing the function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

If the function I want to test is using constants, should I use these constants when testing it?

For example, if this is the function:

```js
export const SERVER_FILTERS = {
  URL: 'pageURL',
  PLATFORM: 'platform',
  TRAFFIC_SOURCE: 'trafficSource',
  COUNTRY: 'country',
  OPERATING_SYSTEM: 'operatingSystem',
  STATE: 'state',
};

export const formatUrlFilterForServer = filter => {
  return filter.conditions.map(({ value }) => {
    return {
      variable: SERVER_FILTERS.URL,
      value,
    };
  });
};
```

Should I use `SERVER_FILTERS` in my test? or is it better to write explicitly the string I want to see in the expected result?

For example:

```js
describe('formatUrlFilterForServer', () => {
  it('should format the URL filter correctly', () => {
    const value = 'blah.com';
    const filter = {
      conditions: [
        { value },
      ],
    };
    const expectedResult = [
      {
        variable: SERVER_FILTERS.URL,
        value,
      },
    ];
    expect(formatUrlFilterForServer(filter)).toEqual(expectedResult)
  })
});
```

On one hand, if I change this constant I don't want to go over all my tests and fix them.
On the other hand, I think my test should find every problem my code could have, even typos in its constants.

Is there a better practice here? thanks everyone.

Comment: Well, what are you testing? An *external API*? How a consumer of that function would use the function? Internal validation?

Comment: I'm unit testing to make sure the function is doing its job. In the case of my example - the consumer would use this function to format some value before sending it to the server.

Comment: So, would the consumer be using constants and/or require specific return values…? E.g. it's no use if the function is required to return a specific string, but you're testing that it's returning a constant which doesn't actually contain that string…

Comment: Can you try to explain again? Not sure I understood what you mean. What I do understand is there's no general approach here I should follow, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You use constants instead of strings when the actual value doesn’t matter much, and you just want to ensure the *same* value is used everywhere. The programming language will tell you when you’ve typoed a constant, it can’t tell you the same for bare strings. So, do you want to test that your function returns the correct constant, or do you care what value exactly is being returned because the actual value itself is meaningful?

Comment: We should use constants for a lot of reasons (code reuse, avoiding typos, compile-time checking, etc.), as you know - "magic strings are bad". My question is, and I'm trying to better explain myself, should the function's unit test avoid using these constants as it should avoid using a helper function the function uses (we usually mimic the helper's output with a mock)? Because the value itself is important here and I'm wondering if using the constants will potentially hide problems the test should find. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

- You use constants to avoid typos, or if the value itself isn’t important and you just need to ensure you’re using the same value everywhere.
- You’re testing the code to ensure it behaves in some specific way.

These are the two axioms to work with here. So the question is, what are you testing? Is the return value itself important or not? Are you testing that your function is returning the expected *value* or the expected meaningless *flag*?

Another thing to ask yourself with unit testing is *what might break if you change something* and *whether your tests will catch that*. If you’re testing that your function returns the expected *constant*, is it an issue if you change those constant values? Your function may now return a different value, but the test—testing for a constant—passes unchanged. Is that desired or not?

So, if your function’s responsibility is to return a specific string value (whose exact expected value may be defined by external forces and must correspond exactly), then you want to test that your function is returning that exact string value. If on the other hand you just want to confirm your function is taking the right logical steps and produces the expected logical state, but its exact value is unimportant, testing for a constant is just fine.

You could of course split the difference too: confirm that your function returns the expected constant, and confirm in a separate test that those constants contain the expected values. You just need to ensure that your tests are catching potential causes of errors.